# How to create java web service for Android application using MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I want to create java web service for register and login android application using  MySQL database. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using any java framework like Spring or Play Framework, where you can design your rest API and connect to android  application.